# Check url schema existence on Android

Tags: android, skype

I can use skype (or any other) application from my android app with url schemes like `'skype://'`.
But can i check existence of schema on user mobile phone? Like `canOpenURL` in iOS
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to check if the intent can be handled:

```
public static boolean intentIsAvailable(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
   final PackageManager mgr = ctx.getPackageManager();
   List<ResolveInfo> list =
      mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
         PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
   return list.size() > 0;
}
```

usage:

```
if(intentIsAvailable(appContext, yourIntent)){
   startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A scheme is meaningless on its own -- it has to be tied to some action (`ACTION_VIEW`, `ACTION_CALL`, etc.) in an `Intent`.

Your Java code can call `resolveActivity()` on `PackageManager` to determine if any given `Intent` will be handled by the system if you were to call `startActivity()` with that `Intent`.

Comment: In other words i can determine skype existence in system?

Comment: @Falcon: No, you can determine if there is something that handles particular actions on the `skype` scheme. Other apps could elect to handle actions on that scheme, if they so chose.